# Query Langauge analogy to Turing Completeness

Tags: programming-languages

Is there a completeness property for query languages (like SQL, Cypher, Datalog, etc) that is analogous to Turing completeness in programming languages? I wondered if it is something like being able to describe any subset of the facts in the database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900055/is-sql-or-even-tsql-turing-complete

Comment: Chapter 18 of [Foundations of Databases](http://webdam.inria.fr/Alice/) by Abiteboul, Hull, and Vianu discusses the relationship between the expressive power of various (theoretical) query languages and specifically highly expressive languages that are "complete" for queries (in a sense they define).